# How can I use JavaScript\JQuery to write some content into a div having a specific id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am pretty new in JavaScript and JQuery and I have the following situation.

Into a page I have something like this:

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    ..............................................
    ..............................................
    ..............................................
    <area data-reveal-id="SA" shape="poly" coords="63,210,74,246,64,290,38,298,30,272,33,218" 
          href="#" alt="Sardegna" onmouseover="RollMapOn('sardegna')" onmouseout="RollMapOff()" onclick="getRegioneSelezionata(this)" />
</map>
```

So this **map** simply represent a mapping on an immage represening a geographic map.

So when the user click on a specific geographical region represented by a **region** tag it is performed the **getRegioneSelezionata(this)** JavaScript function that take as input parameter the reference to the clicked  tag (is it this reasoning correct?).

So this is the code of the **getRegioneSelezionata()** function:

```
function getRegioneSelezionata(regioneSelezionata) {
    var regione = regioneSelezionata.getAttribute("data-reveal-id");
    alert("Regione: " + regione);
}
```

This function simply extract the value of the **data-reveal-id** attribute (clicking on the previous example it is the **SA** value) and print it into an alert popup. It works fine.

Now my problem is that I don't want that this value is printend in the alert popup but do the following thing:

1) Into my page I also have this div having **id="infoRegione"**:

```
<div id="infoRegione" class="jumbotron" style="height: 405px; padding-top: 5px;">
    INFO
</div>
```

So I want that the previous value have to be printed inside this div and not into the alert popup

How can I do this thing?

Another doubt is that the previous **getRegioneSelezionata()** is a standard JavaScript function, can I implement this behavior using JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure js:

```
document.getElementById('infoRegione').innerHTML = regione;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#infoRegione").html(regione);
```

or

```
$("#infoRegione").text(regione);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
alert("Regione: " + regione);
```

With

```
$("#infoRegione").html(regione);
```

The "#" is used for IDs (the same as in CSS)

(You can use "." for classes).

See here for more information:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/

Btw, sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking in your last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using javascript or jquery as follow

```
function getRegioneSelezionata(regioneSelezionata) {
    var regione = regioneSelezionata.getAttribute("data-reveal-id");
    alert("Regione: " + regione);
    // Javascript
    document.getElementById("infoRegione").innerHTML = regione;

   //Jquery
     $("#infoRegione").html(regione);
}
```